# How to partition MBR external hdd on Mac?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partitioning, mbr

I have a 1TB external hard drive and I decided that I would partition it so I could use one for files and one for Time Machine backups. But I found out that my hdd's partition table is Master Boot Record and I can't transfer the data temporarily on my Mac because the data on it is around 50GB and the free space left on my Mac is 15.67GB. Help!

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: I hope by now you’ve found a solution. I don’t think you can partition your MBR drive non-destructively. That’s why newer partition schemes were invented. To my mind, it’s worth buying a relatively cheap USB device to store the data while you’re mucking about with the external drive.

Answer (score 8):

You can use Terminal

```
diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk7 MBR fat32 "NO NAME" 100%
```

Replace number 7 on "disk7" with actual disk number..

- GPT: GUID Partition Table
- APM: Apple Partition Map
- MBR: Master Boot Records

For additional volumes just use this approach

```
Volume1Format Volume1Name Volume1Size Volume2Format Volume2Name Volume2Size
```

For example:

```
diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk7 MBR fat32 FIRST 100m fat32 SECOND 100m
```

Based on that you are able to make your own command.

Comment: The OP wants to create two partitions.  I don’t see how your post supports that.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I have updated my post.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I used the technique to partition a 120Gb USB Flash Drive to half ExFat and half Fat32, all on MBR, which is more recognisable on third party devices. I think, however, that this is destructive, so it may not fill OP’s requirements … ?

Answer (score 1):

You can **shrink your existing partition**, and then add other partitions in the free space of the disk. I think it can be done with Disk Utility, and it definitely can be done with the `diskutil resizeVolume` command. See `man diskutil` or the resizeVolume section in [this page](https://ss64.com/osx/diskutil.html).

If you need to **convert your MBR partition to GUID** (GPT), while keeping the files already on the disk, you can use the [GPT fdisk tools](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) [`cgdisk`](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/cgdisk.html) or [`gdisk`](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/gdisk.html). If you already have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), you can install these tools with

```
brew install --cask gdisk
```

Answer (score 0):

You need another drive to transfer the files to temporarily.

There are applications which can convert MBR to GUID & then repartition without data loss, for instance [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/) - but a backup is highly recommended anyway...
... so, you need another drive.